# How does one identify the weakest preconditions in Hoare triples?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I am trying to understand Dijkstra's weakest precondition inference technique using notes from [here](https://www.cs.williams.edu/%7Efreund/cs326/ReasoningPart1.html). I am following a simple example given over there to compute the weakest precondition -

```
x = x - 2;

z = x + 1;

{ z != 0 }
```

Here is the solution to this problem -

```
{ x != -1 }

x = x - 2;

{ x != -1 }

z = x + 1;

{ z != 0 }
```

I don't understand the part where, `{ x != -1 }`. Shouldn't it be `{ x != 1 }`?

**Edit 1**

I apologize for not clearly stating my confusion.

I completely understand the precondition `{ x != -1 }` for the statement `z = x + 1`.

My confusion arises in the following statement - `x = x - 2`

Over here, we know that we don't want `x` (rhs) to be -1. Therefore, (if I understand correct) we need to set up a precondition on x (lhs). For `{x!=-1}`, the lhs x should be `{x!=1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  The first precondition should be `{x≠1}`, not `{x≠-1}`.  It's probably a typographic error.